# I need a tool to analyze log Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming, hadoop-plugins

I have log files from Hadoop
I want to analyze these large files to generate as a report, So I am looking for a convenient tool for the analysis of these files. Please introduce tools for the analysis of these files.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try LogStash or better to say ELK Stack.

For your help i am mentioning few googled links/blogs by other people that may hep you:
[Link1](http://www.tupp.me/2014/04/three-way-to-use-logstash-with-hadoop.html), [Link2](http://www.paluch.biz/blog/95-logging-hadoop-messages-into-logstash-using-logstash-gelf.html) ,[Link3](https://tech-stories.com/2015/02/12/setting-up-a-central-logging-infrastructure-for-hadoop-and-spark/)